# msgpack - configure messagepack without attribute

Tags: c#, msgpack

I want to use msgpack to submit data between c# and javascript.
Problem is I cannot add attributes to the classes.

Is there a way to configure msgpack without using attributes?

Comment: Yes, there is. https://github.com/neuecc/MessagePack-CSharp

Comment: It seems you need to take a look at these two: https://github.com/neuecc/MessagePack-CSharp#object-serialization and https://github.com/neuecc/MessagePack-CSharp#resolvers